# How to use custom fonts in HTML?

Tags: html

I have a .ttf file downloaded locally from dafonts.com, and I was wondering how to easily use it in my website. It is called Batman Forever (Link:https://www.dafont.com/batman-forever.font). Any help for a novice?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    body {
    height: 3000px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #7c0fb8 85%);
    }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <center>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to see the font work on just my header ("Hello"). The current output is in the default font.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it in the style (an example) :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;(choose the name for your font here)
    src:local("C:\Users\Website\fonts\Harlow_Solid_Italic.ttf");(put the link of font in your local computer)
}

body{
    font-family: myFirstFont; (write your font name here)
}
```

Comment: Didn't work... Am I supposed to keep the parentheses? (sorry for being stupid, brand spankin' new to coding)

Comment: Just guess but I think that's because the link to your font is wrong (in src).
You can find docs in here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: You use the local link in your pc I wrote just an example of syntax